# How to change the default value of a python library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-libraries, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to create charts, I want to know if there is a way to change the default style value directly in the library.

So I don't have to always change it in each new graphic.

Comment: code, show us some code

Comment: Do you want to edit the library, maybe?

Comment: @Gameplay  man I want to know how to change the default value of a library, what code will I put?

Comment: @Nineteendo Yes

Comment: You can try to monkey patch it then

Answer (score 0):

Is it global variable? Then:

```
global my_var
my_var="new_value"
```

Is it class/instance property? Then:

```
Some_obj.some_field = "new_value"
```

Also, there may be some setters to do it. If they are presented, use them. Like:

```
Some_obj.set_default_style(arg1, arg2)
```

Also, if default style is a class, you can subclass it and customize as you want.

Answer (score 0):

def student(firstname, lastname ='Mark', standard ='Fifth'):

```
print(firstname, lastname, 'studies in', standard, 'Standard')
```

Comment: Use code blocks for formatting:
```python
def here_is():
    return 'some_code'
```